# ShareLaTeX and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I'm writing my thesis with my friend but I'm having serious problems getting `biblatex` to work with [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/), it apparently has support (according to this blog: http://www.clarusft.com/sharelatex/).

However, I can't get it to work properly, or at all to be honest.

I have included this in the top.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} % I try to use biber.
\bibliography{ref} % the ref.bib file
\begin{document}

Hi there, Stackoverflowers\cite{lol}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

And here is my `ref.bib` file:

```
@article
{lol,
author = "Anders Ekholm",
title = "Den ljusnande framtid är vård",
year = "2010" 
}
```

This doesn't work.

I get the errors:

```
main.tex:55 Citation 'lol' on page 1 undefined. 
main.tex:274 Empty bibliography. 
undefined:undefined There were undefined references.
undefined:undefined [biblatex] Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards. (page 23)
```

Comment: With `backend=bibtex` it works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: If you haven't seen this already: http://www.sharelatex.com/help/discussions/suggestions/40-biber-support-in-sharelatex

Comment: James from ShareLaTeX here. Sorry that we're a bit behind the times with our lack of biber support. Bibtex should work though. I've bumped this up our todo list since I think it's catching people out. Feel free to drop us a support query directly if you ever have similar problems again.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, I feel really great about your direct support here, and I will try to use the support thingy. However, Stackexchange works really well with being placed on google search results, since they are so often relevant, so maybe I'll try to post on both places.

Comment: we now have some bibliography templates, including a basic Bibtex example, which you can look at to help things https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/bibliographies

Comment: @jpallen I am experiencing exactly the same problem. However, I cannot make it work even with backend=bibtex. I copy/pasted the code and used a sample *.bib file. I think there is a major bug here.

Comment: As of today, the biber backend works in sharelatex.

Answer (score 4):

Luckily, this answer is **outdated**, ShareLaTeX now supports biber.
See the other answers if you still have problems.

---

[jpallen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16641/jpallen) wrote in the comment:

> James from ShareLaTeX here. Sorry that we're a bit behind the times
>   with our lack of Biber support. BibTeX should work though. I've bumped
>   this up our todo list since I think it's catching people out. Feel
>   free to drop us a support query directly if you ever have similar
>   problems again.

Comment: It looks like almost two years later, biber is still not supported by ShareLaTeX. Is that correct?

Comment: Total of humanity's hours lost due to this bug: +1

Comment: @Christoph No. ShareLaTeX supports biber.

Answer (score 2):

I've just managed ShareLaTeX (and Overleaf) to work with biber backend. I've found two ways:

1. Include the content of your .bib file into the main file

   ```
   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents}{bib}
   your bib file contents goes here
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{bib}
   ```
2. use the path specifier when adding your .bib file

   ```
   \addbibresource{./ref.bib}
   ```

By the way, you should use command `\addbibresource{}` in BibLaTeX, and not `\bibliography{ref}`

Here's the [link](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/56167756212befaf688721f5) to ShareLaTeX project with your MWE, and here's the [same](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bycqhykvhvtm) repeated on Overleaf.

Comment: I don't think the first item is a requirement. In ShareLaTeX you can upload a file to form part of your project. The second option also seems superfluous given that you don't use that notation in the first. The main problem seems to be that the OP used `\bibliography` instead of `\addbibresource`.

Comment: I've made a project on ShareLaTeX to illustrate the second option. The same .bib resource is added with and without dot slash. You can try to comment/uncomment the corresponding lines and see what happens.

Comment: What I'm trying to point out is that your answer is not consistent. The first option *doesn't* use `./` while the second *does*.

Comment: yes, you're true. And I don't know why. And I have just checked once again, to make it work on ShareLatex, I've actually used `\bibliography{./ref}`. and with `\addbibresource{}` option 2 seems not to work anyway. I'm puzzled now...

Comment: Mhhh, I just played around with sharelatex and everything worked fine even if I didn't include the `./` part. Even in your example there was no trouble with `\addbibresource{ref.bib}`. `\bibliography{ref}` worked as well (even though it is officially deprecated in `biblatex`)

Answer (score 1):

As @Evpoc wrote in the comments, Sharelatex supports biber for quite some time now. However, I several times still received that error message.

I found that changing `\addbibresource{ref.bib}` to `\addbibresource{ref}`, compiling, changing it back and compiling again resolves the problem.

I suspect it is caused by some temporary files of biber that Sharelatex does not remove upon `clear cached files`.