# Package biblatex Warning: Data encoding is 'utf8'. Use backend=biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, warnings

After a few days break I went back to working on a report. When I tried to compile I got the following warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Data encoding is 'utf8'.
(biblatex)                Use backend=biber.
```

I haven't changed a thing since last week, when it worked. I did open the file on someone else's laptop, but didn't touch the code. I am using ShareLaTeX. The relevant code is (I think):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\printbibliography
```

References are in the form of:

```
@book{griffiths,
    author        = {D.J. Griffiths},
    title         = {Introduction to Quantum Mechanics},
    year          = {2005},
    publisher     = {Pearson Education Inc.},
    location      = {USA, New Jersey, Upper Saddle River}
}
```

EDIT: When I change the backend to biber, the file doesn't recognise any references, and the log says:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                output
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I'm unsure how to do this in ShareLaTeX. Consider me a simple mortal, who is not knowledgeable about much outside of basic report writing.

Comment: Just change `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber`. `bibtex` can only handle files in ascii encoding.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that doing that causes the file to not recognise any references. Sorry about that.

Comment: Did you rerun biber and latex, as said in the .log?

Comment: I'm unsure how I do that. ShareLaTeX only has this big 'Compile/Recompile' button, instead of separate ones for .bib and .tex files. Repeatedly pressing that did not fix the problem. Clearing the cache didn't help either.

Comment: As far as I know, ShareLaTeX does not support Biber, so you are stuck with BibTeX. The original warning (it is not an error) suggests that your document (I suppose the `.bib` file) was recognised as being UTF8 encoded (probably due to an UTF8 character), `biblatex` suggests you use Biber as this back-end is able to deal with UTF8 while BibTeX is not. So you can either ignore the warning (but keep an eye open for mangled characters and other encoding issues) or make sure your `.bib` file at least is 100% ASCII (I'm not sure whether UTF8 in the `.tex` file also triggers the warning).

Comment: If you choose to make your `.bib` file `ascii`-encoded (or similar), but want your document to remain in `utf8`, you might have to use the `bibencoding` option, please refer to §2.4.3.4 *Specifying Encodings*, pp. 41-43 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). Also make sure you properly escape non `ascii`-chars (see [How to write “ä” and other umlauts  ...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864) or refer to [`biblatex-examples.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib)).

Comment: The line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is the reason for that, right? I suppose I have no reason to use `utf8` over `ascii`, at least for now. Removing that line fixed the problem, so thank you!

Comment: That is one way to fix the problem, yes. In general, `biblatex` needs t know the encoding of both the `.tex` and the `.bib` file (it is good at guessing, but sometimes things can go wrong (see the section in the documentation I linked to above)). If `biblatex` suspects you want UTF8 and you use BibTeX you get a warning since BibTeX cannot support UTF8. So removing `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and thereby effectively reverting to `acii` gets rid of the warning.

Comment: @moewe sharelatex supports biber

Comment: @Guido Oh, OK, I thought I had in the back of my mind that sharelatex did not support Biber, when I googled it, it found [this feature request from](http://help.sharelatex.com/help/discussions/suggestions/40-biber-support-in-sharelatex) March 2013. Could you write up an answer for [ShareLaTeX and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102443/35864) on how to use Biber with shareLaTeX as obviously it did not seem to work here at first.

Comment: The warning is not related to the bib file or bibltex "knowing" something about the content of the bib file. It is triggered by the inputenc option. biblatex guesses that if your document uses utf8 then perhaps the bib-file and perhaps there are non-ascii chars and perhaps something could go wrong. If your bib-file has only english entries I wouldn't worry. And if you have non-ascii chars: Check their output.

Comment: @Guido Want to write an answer at [ShareLaTeX and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102443) so we can close this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is in the comments, but since nobody wrote an complete answer, I will.

Bibtex requires ascii encoding. If your document is set to utf8 encoding, bibtex will assume the bib file also is utf8. Therefore, you have to be sure your bib file is ascii encoded, and you have to tell bibtex to consider it as ascii.

In your case, biblatex package should be loaded with the following options:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii,style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

The other option is to use biber as backend. In that case, the bib file can be utf8 encoded.