# Bibliography on the footer of each page - ShareLatex

Tags: bibliographies, sharelatex

This is the code that I'm using:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
```

But I want to put the references on the footer of each page. How can I put them there? Which package or command should I use?

Example:
 postimg.org/image/p4048ijzd

Comment: No I want the bibliography that I cite on the text for example \cite{web1} where web1 is @Misc{web1, ...} . This bibliography is on a new page. I want in each page the respective bibliography references of this page, on the footer of the page.

Comment: Like this: http://postimg.org/image/p4048ijzd/

Comment: you want bibliography as footnote?

Comment: Yeah like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following MWE you can use `\footcite`. Note that you have to use `biblatex` and `biber` to compile the MWE!

If you can't use `biber` change the `biblatex` option `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex`.

MWE (name it for example `mwe.tex`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, % <=============== possible: bibtex, bibtex8, biber
  style=authortitle,
  citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
  sorting=nyt,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \autocite{adams}. 
And \footcite{mozart:KV183}.

\nocite{*} % <===== shows all uncited bib entrys in bibliography
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Mozart is cited with `\footcite`. Also note, that your given code sbippets are based on BiBTeX, not Biber and `biblatex`.

Compile it with `pdflatex mwe.tex`, then `biber mwe`, then two times `pdflatex mwe.tex`.  To avoid problems with your editor (which one do you use?) compile with this commands on the terminal/console.

If you use BiBTeX as backend change the compiling to: `pdflatex mwe.tex`, then `bibtex mwe`, then two times `pdflatex mwe.tex`.

Please have a look on the following question [ShareLaTeX and `biblatex` with Biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102443/sharelatex-and-biblatex)

Comment: But i'm using sharelatex. How can I compile this?

Comment: It's another way without biber and bibtex?

Comment: I already change my title of the question thanks!