# Bibliography in the footer of each page

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sharelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\footcite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
This is text with \cite{Goossens}. 
And\footcite{mozart:KV183}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

I'm making this to put bibliography in the footer of each page. But nly appears the last name of the author or a (?) . What I'm making wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the part with `filecontents`from my mwe to your older [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280190/bibliography-on-the-footer-of-each-page-sharelatex) to the code above:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}
```

This creates a file `mwe.bib` if you use the code inside a file `mwe.tex`.  That's the reason you have line `\bibliography{\jobname.bib}` in your given code: `\jobname` changes to `mwe` and the bib file used is so `mwe.bib`.

Complete code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\footcite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
This is text with \cite{Goossens}. 
And\footcite{mozart:KV183}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <===================================

\end{document}
```

Please see that you have to delete the file extention `.bib` in the third last line: change `\bibliography{\jobname.bib}` to `\bibliography{\jobname}`.  Then the code compiles. Do not forget to compile `pdflatex`, `bibtex`,  `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

Result is then:

[image]

Comment: When I cite websites, the reference appears web(?) . How can I solve the problem? I cite the websites with @misc{web, howpublished={\url{www.something.com}},title={something},note={accessed in november}} for example